# Virtualbox 64bit image on 64bit computer without virtualization support

Tags: virtualbox, 64bit

I have a 64 bit image for VirtualBox (.vmdk file), and I don't have a 32 bit version. My computer doesn't support hardware virtualization.

Logically VirtualBox says:

> This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU. Unable to boot - please a kernel appropriate for your CPU.

If I don't have a 32 bit version, does that simply mean I am screwed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, yes, you are, as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

[VirtualBox is incapable of virtualizing 64-bit operating systems without CPU hardware virtualization support.](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#intro-64bitguests)

> 1. You need a 64-bit processor with hardware virtualization support.
> 2. You must enable hardware virtualization for the particular VM for which you want 64-bit support; software virtualization is not supported for 64-bit VMs.
> 3. If you want to use 64-bit guest support on a 32-bit host operating system, you must also select a 64-bit operating system for the particular VM. Since supporting 64 bits on 32-bit hosts incurs additional overhead, VirtualBox only enables this support upon explicit request.

See also: [Hardware vs. software virtualization](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch10.html#hwvirt).